# Printing content of file from nth line to nth line [Shell Scripting]

Tags: shell-script, scripting

**

**> Hey buddies I have a file having names of 200 countries.I want to print names of countries from 50th line to 80th line .How can  i do so in bash??**

**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Comment: Please edit your Q to show minimal input file and what are you trying. Just an `awk` command would do as in `awk 'NR==50,NR==80' file`.